# Javafx WebEngine calling Javascript window.location.hash doesn't work

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I tried different solution to make my webview point to a specific anchor in the document but failed. 
my target name is `'occ'`
I used `window.location.hash = 'occ'`  and `window.location.href ='#occ'`but didn't work here my code

```
    contentView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
        public void changed(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
            if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                System.out.println("loaded");
                doc = contentView.getEngine().getDocument();
                JSObject windowObject = (JSObject) contentView.getEngine().executeScript("window");
                windowObject.call("scrollTo", 0, 600);//this works
                contentView.getEngine().executeScript("location.hash = 'occ'"); // doesn't work
                windowObject.call("location.hash", "occ");  // doesn't work
            }
        }
    });
```

here the part of the code where i create anchor

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document d = Jsoup.parse(new File(doc.get("path")), "utf-8");
String searchedPage = d.toString();
for (String keyword : keywordsArray) {
    searchedPage = searchedPage.replaceAll(keyword,
    "<a id='occ' name='occ'><span style='font-weight:bold; background:yellow'>" + keyword + "</span></a>");
 }
contentEngine.loadContent(searchedPage);
```

Comment: I getting the same problem, any solution?